# Как "связать" двух игроков между собой? PHP/Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, разработка-игр, сессия

Делаю монополию для того, чтобы прокачать навыки, худо-бедную логику игры я прописал, дизайн сделал. Но встрял на вопросе как создать сессию, чтобы я, к примеру, мог с друзьями подключиться и играть вместе. Был бы счастлив, если бы мне посоветовали что для этого нужно изучить/показали какой-то наглядный пример.
Я так это вижу:

Нужны имена пользователей, либо их ID, создать сессию(вот тут я в аврале. Гуглил, но скорее всего я глупый и, возможно, тороплюсь, поэтому не нашел для себя внятной информации), и дальше при помощи Ajax обновлять визуал(положение соперника) у 2-го игрока, пока ходит первый и наоборот.
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вам бы, конечно, websocket использовать, иначе вы начнете досить свой сервер запросами. Можете посмотреть вот эту статью с проектом: https://nuancesprog.ru/p/10699/, там по большей степени нода, но в целом будет понятен принцип построения самой архитектуры для игры

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, Спасибо! Скорее всего, легкого пути я не найду. Придется изучать. XD